# Approach for mapping one-to-many in sql without ORM

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, orm

Let's say I have an entity.

```
class Building {
  List<Floor> floors;
  List<Elevator> elevators; 
}
```

For the simplicity Floor and Elevator has  only `id`. And Building has `id, elevator_id, floor_id`

So the query to get all the Buildings with all the floors and all the elevators would be:

```
select 
      id, 
      floor.id as floor_id, 
      elevator.id as elevator_id 
from building 
left join floor on (floor.building_id = building.id)
left join elevator on (elevator.building_id = building.id)
```

Now let's say that I have 1 building with 2 floors and 2 elevators. Query will give a result set like:

```
 id|floor_id|elevator_id
 1   f1        e1
 2   f2        e2
 1   f1        e2
 2   f2        e1
```

So 4 records. The way to parse them:

1. Go not row-by-row, but column-by-column.
2. Create each entity separately
3. Remove duplicates
4. Merge all entities into the proper structure.

So the question is - is there a better approach to solve the problem? And also do ORM does the same thing under the hood or it doesn't?

Not looking for the specific library since I'm trying to figure out how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Run several queries

A smart ORM should run 2-3 queries:

1. A query fetching all buildings, and possibly their floors
2. A query fetching floors (if not already fetched)
3. A query fetching all elevators

Once these queries are executed, the data can be merged again in the client. It's not a good idea, neither in SQL, nor with an ORM, to do it all in one go using to-many left joins as you will create a cartesian product between floors and elevators with your suggested SQL. Imagine if both left joins produce 1000 rows per building, you'll get 1000000 rows of duplicate data, even if each building only has 2000 children.

#### Side note on multisets

Do note that the SQL standard has a `MULTISET()` operator, which would be the best choice here, but very few RDBMS implement it:

```sql
select 
  building.*,
  multiset(select * from floor where floor.building_id = building.id),
  multiset(select * from elevator where elevator.building_id = building.id)
from building
```

Many databases support XML and JSON, so a workaround using those formats might help solve this problem, if you could abstract it well enough. I'm not aware of any ORMs currently doing this in Java. [jOOQ has it on the roadmap](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3884), but it's not implemented. [Neither is Hibernate's version](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9558).